# How to get PDF from characteristic function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, self-learning, characteristic-functions

I would appreciate if anybody could explain to me with a simple example how to find PDF of a random variable from its characteristic function. Thank you.

Comment: [Characteristic function: Inversion formulae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29#Inversion_formulas)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a consequence of Levy's Inversion Formula (aka Fourier Inversion Theorem). If $\varphi$ is the CF of $X$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\varphi(\theta)|d\theta < \infty$ then $X$ is absolutely continuous with density
$$
f(x)= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_\mathbb{R}e^{-i\theta x}\varphi(\theta)d\theta.
$$

(Here we are using the definition $\varphi(\theta) = E[e^{i\theta X}]$, else the constant factor out front might be different.)

Once we know this result it is easy to calculate the density given a CF, just plug into the formula. For example, plug in $\varphi(\theta)= \exp(-\frac12 \theta^2)$ and check that you get $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac12 x^2)$, this is the case of $X \sim N(0,1)$.

Comment: Hey , I know comment is quite late , but it would be really helpful if you could tell $ f(x)  $ of characteristic function = $( {1- |t|})^{-1}$