# Get PDF from Taylor series of characteristic function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, self-learning, characteristic-functions

This question represents some thoughts about the following question: [How to get PDF from characteristic function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/495641/how-to-get-pdf-from-characteristic-function)

In that question $$f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-itx}\phi(t)dt,$$
where $\phi(t)$ is a characteristic function.

What if it is hard to find this integral? But the Taylor series expansion of $\phi(t)$ is $$\phi(t)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_k(it)^k$$

Then $$f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-itx}\phi(t)dt=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-itx}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_k(it)^k\right)dt=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_k\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-itx}(it)^k dt=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k c_k \operatorname{dirac}^{(k)}(x)$$

Does it make any sense?

I think that I'm wrong somewhere because the sum of the derivatives of the Dirac delta function still gives zero on a plot.

Thank you.

Comment: how do you get from the integral of exp to the dirac delta?

Comment: Inverse Fourier Transform of the power function is the k-th derivative of the Dirac delta function.